# "C like struct" in Lua for LONG BUFFER manipulation?

Tags: lua

I am wanting to code "mappings" in Lua rather than in C for the simplicity and beauty of Lua ;-)

So lets say in C I could have had the following:

```
typedef struct my_struct{
    char field_1[10];                              
    char field_2[250];                                
    char field_3[2000];                              
}my_struct;

my_struct   *pmy_struct;

pmy_struct = (my_struct *) some_buffer;
```

So I am wanting a way in Lua to have FIXED lengths on fields inside a "structure" so that the overall BUFFER OFFSETS stay in tact when it reaches the target system....

**So lets say in the above struct I wanted to set "field_3" to the text "apple"......I still want that structure field to have an overall length of 2000 bytes...**

Comment: What is your intent? Why do you need the fields to have fixed lengths? What problem are you trying to solve? There's probably a way to accomplish what you want in Lua. However, you've analyzed the problem yourself, deciding you need "fixed width 'mappings'", then asking how to do *that*. If you instead [told us what the core problem is](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms), we may be able to help you solve it in Lua.

Comment: SAP uses IDOCS (long stream of bytes). IDocs have a field called SDATA which is 1000 bytes and this field holds the "business data" at specific offsets. For example, if 25 bytes of the 1000 bytes is the "material number" but at runtime the material number is only 10 bytes long, I wanted a way to easily "pad" the field so that it fills up the 25 bytes so that when the message hits SAP that SAP can read the business data at the correct offsets. I am using Lua for the mappings into this IDoc format, I used to use C and think I will have to go back to C now ;-( Thanks for your comments though ;-)

Comment: AKA, you're reading a binary file format. If you just want to be able to point to a region of memory and say "interpret thusly" by casting a pointer to a structure with fixed sized fields, then you're going to need C. If you just want to be able to read it into memory and write it back out, then you could do that trivially in Lua, it's just going to require more typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua doesn't work that way. Lua does not have "structures". It does not have "fields" which have "sizes".

It has tables, which can have values of several different types. These values are mapped to keys (which are themselves values). While you can use metatables to prevent the addition of new keys, you can't force the "size" of a value to be anything in particular.

Or, to put it another way, *stop trying to program Lua like it's C.* They are different languages, and you should approach each language in its own way. In C, you want to care about the size of fields, the layout of structs, etc.

The reason to use Lua (and most scripting languages) is because you *don't* want to care about those things. You don't want to care if the string "apple" happens to be stored in a byte array 2000 bytes in size. And if you want to care about that, then you don't want to use Lua.

Comment: He might care about the width of fields for purposes of some file or network stream format. Perfectly doable in Lua. Unfortunately, rather than telling us the problem he's trying to solve, he's asking how to implement a solution he's devised for an unstated problem, limiting our ability to help.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with Lua.

If you wish to (or are forced to) stay with Lua 5.1, consider using the [struct](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/) library.

```
raw_data = struct.pack("c10c250c2000", field1, field2, field3)
field1, field2, field3 = struct.unpack("c10c250c2000", raw_data)
```

However, the best solution available at the moment is [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html); there are numerous benefits to using LuaJIT over the standard Lua implementation, but the one that most applies to you is the [FFI library](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html).

```
local ffi = require"ffi"
ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct {
        char field_1[10];                              
        char field_2[250];                                
        char field_3[2000];                              
    } my_struct;
]]

local my_thing = ffi.new("my_struct")
my_thing.field_1 = "Ain't"
my_thing.field_2 = "this"
my_thing.field_3 = "great? :D"

local ptr_my_thing = ffi.new("my_struct*", my_thing)
ptr_my_thing.field_2 = [[
    LuaJIT does a great job at figuring out
    what you're trying to do.
]]
ptr_my_thing.field_3 = [[
    There are some cases where the generics of
    Lua cannot be used to infer information,
    so have a look at the LuaJIT site for specifics.
]]

print(ffi.string(ptr_my_thing.field_2))
```

It is a common misconception that generalised languages such as Lua and Python should not (or, in ignorance, cannot) be used for low-level specifics.
LuaJIT is a major first step for "smart" language that allow you to work at any level.

Comment: +1 your solution is cool, can you please post the C side of it too ? Do i do lua_newuserdata or lua_pushsring form the C side.I couldnt find even one example for luajit on the C side.

Comment: I wrote a bunch about "C -> Lua -> C Struct" but it vanished! In brief: `struct.pack` does not follow any C compiler semantics; call it via the C API and do not try to cast it to a C struct. The FFI library however can be used to generate proper C data with padding and all (it follows GCC data layout semantics). You can access a C struct by making a pointer to it and passing it as lightuserdata, which can be casted. As for the other way round, I'm not sure... you'll have to experiment! Be careful to either keep a reference or use `malloc` and `free` appropriately (Lua GCs FFI data).

Comment: Oh, in case you're unsure, the FFI library was *not* intended to be used with the C API; there are many issues when trying to do anything but pass simple data and pointers (even troubles with that). The FFI library can be used from LuaJIT only, without any C. It's fast... very fast. I've been working on using FFI with the C API to create an efficient interface between host and Lua (for the game Natural Selection 2, namely). Is this what you're trying to do?