# lua newbie : C-Lua How to pass a struct/buffer to lua from C?

Tags: lua

I followed this boiler plate example: http://www.matrix44.net/blog/?p=456

I am able to send string across from C to Lua, but I am getting an error when I pass a struct (i used lua_newuserdata).

#### C snip

```c
//s = (ST*) malloc ( sizeof(ST) );
//    lua_pushlightuserdata(state, s);
s = lua_newuserdata(state, sizeof(ST));
s->a=11;
s->b=12;
printf ( "s = %p \n", s ); // Prints 0x80a708
result = lua_pcall(state, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
```

---

#### Lua snip

```
print(foo)  -->  Prints 0x80a708
io.write("received has:\n", foo.a); --> ERROR : Failed to run script: script.lua:1: attempt to index global 'foo' (a userdata value)
```

---

How do i cast the buffer into a  struct/table-record?

Ultimately, my C program doesn't know the struct it will only pass the buffer to Lua and Lua knows the struct and need to be cast there.

Thanks,
PS : the printf of both the script and C program matches (0x80a708), can I just cast ??

Comment: There are no predefined operations on `userdata` values in Lua except for assignment and equality test. You would have to define how a lookup works using the userdata's metatable. ... Also, if your C program doesn't know the struct, but Lua does - where does it come from?

Comment: basically, the C program is a broker that passes to Lua [ assume it as a client that knows the struc type ] this buffer that server sends .

Comment: The problem is, with any approach, all you will get in C is the member name as a string (either with using a table or a userdatum with an `__index` metamethod). I don't know of a way to return a struct's member just from having it's name in a string - unless you create some kind of table (or `switch` statement) that maps those strings to members/offsets - and you will have to do that explicitly, for which in turn you have to know the members of the struct.

Comment: SOLVED : I used luajit and was able to pass a buffer and cast it to C struct on the lua side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : I used luajit and was able to pass a buffer and cast it to C struct on the lua side.

Comment: What did u used for that ? `cdata = ffi.cast(ct, init)` or `ctype = ffi.metatype(ct, metatable)` ? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Lua doesn't have structs, it has tables.

Userdata is a convenient way to pass opaque data to Lua, but Lua won't be able to see inside. Userdata is only useful if you pass it back to C++ and you have a way to determine what it is (essentially casting it to the right type).

Lua tables are the closest to a struct in C++. You can write something like this:

```
lua_newtable(state);
lua_pushnumber(state, s->a);
lua_setfield(state, -2, "a");
lua_pushnumber(state, s->b);
lua_setfield(state, -2, "b");
```

With this, now you can refer to it in lua:

```
print(foo.a); -- this will now print 11
```

Comment: I know tables. my C program is not aware of the struct it is only a broker passing the buffer to lua, so how do i cast that buffer to a lua struct or table ? Iam still reading indexing, but dont get it.

Comment: You need C, at some point, to know the structure of the buffer. Lua by itself won't be able to do it, as a C struct is simply a bunch of offsets to a pointer and is generated by the compiler. The only safe way you can access a C struct is through C.

If you don't have the representation at construction time, you can create a metatable and attach it to the userdata you used originally. Then, implement __index for the metatable to return the appropriate value. This you'll have to do in C. Take a look at this for an idea on how to use metatables to index values: http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html

Comment: @purpletech Alternatively, if you mostly need Lua to understand the structure, you can treat it as a Lua table on both ends. In this way, instead of having a native C struct, you'd have a LuaTable class, that has methods like GetField (or GetNumber, if you don't use templates).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607372/c-like-struct-in-lua-for-long-buffer-manipulation

Answer (score 2):

Userdata internals are inaccessible from Lua code.
Use a table for passing struct from C to Lua.
Or manually define indexing for your userdata through metatable.