# Pass a read-only buffer from C to Lua

Tags: c, lua

I'd like to pass an opaque data buffer from C to Lua without actually copying all the data (since it could be very large 100s of MBs or GBs).

More specifically, I have a C snippet that looks like this:

```
uint8_t *buffer = // points to some memory
size_t size = // size of the buffer
```

My C program doesn't know the structure of the data in the buffer. It is completely oblivious to it. It will never touch this data for anything aside from calling the Lua function responsible for consuming this data.

My goal is to pass this buffer to Lua, which will then interpret the contents of the data and perform all kinds of actions based on it (the Lua code knows how to determine the structure of the data based on its contents or size). Furthermore, the Lua code will not modify the buffer (only read from it).

Below is some sample pseudocode of my ideal functionality:

```
bool perform_action(lua_State *L, uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {

   // Pass buffer to lua
   // call "process_buffer" function (written in Lua)
   // get return from "process_buffer" function (a boolean)
   // free(buffer);
   // return the result above
}
```

This question, I think, is related to: [lua newbie : C-Lua How to pass a struct/buffer to lua from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396067/lua-newbie-c-lua-how-to-pass-a-struct-buffer-to-lua-from-c). However, the solution in that thread is: "Use LuaJIT" which doesn't make any sense to me.

A potential solution is using:

```
lua_pushlstring (L, buffer, size);
```

but wouldn't this make a copy of the data? Is there a way to do this with zero-copy (since the data is quite large)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply write and expose this function to Lua `read_part_of_buffer(start_offset, length, return_this_part_as_number_instead_of_string)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noticed, `lua_pushlstring` is the usual way to push raw data to Lua in form of a string. To avoid a copy, you need to push a weak pointer to Lua, which leads you to **userdata**. But how to reinterpret this userdata in Lua as a string? Short: you can't! With **LuaJIT** you could cast userdata to a CData pointer (your userdata would be a structure, which holds your buffer + size) - easy & direct. Without, you have to *copy* by adding a metatable to your userdata which allows to extract pieces as strings and request the size.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a userdata which contains a pointer to the buffer and its size, and implement an `__index` metamethod which permits to grab an individual byte and push it to lua.

Depending on the details of your lua script, this userdata could be used as a drop-in replacement for the string type used by the script, or you might have to implement more metamethods like `__len` and such.

If your script really requires that the data be represented by a string, then you are most likely SOL. Lua requires to manage itself the data in strings, so you must copy it to a buffer owned by lua if you want it to be represented exactly as a string type in the script.

To be sure of your needs you would have to post your code.